# I need to call an url from localhost but I get $.ajax is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

At the moment i am testing all on localhost but in my live version i am  to call a online (http) url.

I have included the latest jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now the main part of my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {


                $('#theBarcodeA').keyup(function (e) {
                    barcodeA = $(this);
                    // if Enter key was pressed, send the barcode to backend 
                    if ((e.keyCode == 13) && (barcodeA.val().length > 2)) {

                        $('#theBarcodeB').focus();
                        //clean the message/status
                        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = '';

                    }

                });
                $('#theBarcodeB').keyup(function (e) {
                    barcodeB = $(this);
                    // if Enter key was pressed, send the barcode to backend 
                    if ((e.keyCode == 13) && (barcodeB.val().length > 2)) {

                        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = barcodeA.val()+' '+barcodeB.val();//just testing
                        var codeA = barcodeA.val();
                        var codeB = barcodeB.val();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://localhost/testdomain.com/scannerconnector/connectBars.php",
                            data: 'barcodeA=' + codeA + '&barcodeB=' + codeB,
                            success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
                                $("#status").html(data);
                                // document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = data;
                            }
                        });


                    }

                });


            });
```

but i get the  " $.ajax is not a function"  error message

Comment: did you load jquery?

Comment: @Hekmat the code could not have made it to the `$.ajax()` call without jQuery.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, fwiw, there's no reason to use `document.querySelector()`. That's what the `$()` function does.

Comment: @Pointy well the strange thing is if i replace  document.querySelector with $ the inner html doesn't update

Comment: You'd need `$("#status").html(data)` - jQuery returns a jQuery object, so you have to use jQuery APIs and not native DOM APIs.

Comment: @alex html() in jquery innerHTML in js

Comment: Any other library loaded in page that might also use `$()`?

Comment: Right, or is it possible that there's another jQuery import that's grabbing one of the "slim" builds without ajax?

Comment: @Pointy and charlietfl you are correct. I totally overlooked 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js' which has been imported as well

Comment: second load overwrites whole `$` object and there's the problem

Comment: @charlietfl how do make the ajax call without jquery? I found this but wasn't  able to get it to work see first answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @alex: Visit http://youmightnotneedjquery.com and type in `ajax` in the search field at the bottom. Solutions will show up below. All of that code can be easily written without jQuery.